# "Être adoré par" et "être adoré de"

Tags: prépositions, de, passif

> Le roi a été adoré **par** son peuple.
>
> Le roi a été adoré **de** son peuple.

Quelle est la différence entre ces deux phrases ? De plus, laquelle correspond à la voix active ci-dessous ?

> Le peuple a adoré son roi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont à la voix passive et correspondent à la forme active de : « Le peuple a adoré son roi.».

Le complément d'agent d'un verbe à la voix passive peut être introduit *par* ou par *de*.

**Version courte** de cours de [FLE](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/passif_par_de.htm) :

> PAR ou DE au passif ?
>   La majorité des verbes sont suivis de PAR.  Certains verbes sont suivis de DE : accompagné de..., admiré de..., adoré de..., aimé de..., apprécié de..., bordé de..., connu de..., couvert de..., décoré de..., détesté de..., entouré de..., équipé de..., estimé de..., fatigué de..., haï de..., lassé de..., précédé de..., respecté de..., suivi de... etc.

C'est déjà plus nuancé dans [ce cours pour étudiants avancés](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/445.html) et c'est Grevisse qui donne une image claire en faisant le tour de la question. Je condense ci-dessous :

**Version longue**

> Le complément d'agent du verbe passif est introduit par une des
>    prépositions *par* ou *de*. L'usage n'a établi, pour l'emploi de
>    chacune de ces prépositions devant le complément d'agent, aucune règle stricte. Toutefois on peut observer ce qui suit :
>
> 1° *De* s'emploie surtout quand le sens propre du verbe s'est affaibli et qu'on exprime, plutôt que l'action même, l'état résultant de l'action subie. *Par* s'emploie surtout quand le verbe garde son sens plein et présente à l'esprit l'idée de l'action.
>
> 2° *De* s'emploie souvent avec les verbes pris au figuré. *Par* s'emploie plutôt avec les verbes pris au propre.
>
> - *Il était accablé de honte.*
> - *Il était accablé par la charge*.
>
> 3° *De* s'emploie souvent avec les verbes marquant un sentiment, une émotion de l'âme. *Par* s'emploie plutôt avec les verbes indiquant une opération matérielle.
>
> - *J'étais craint de mes ennemis et aimé de mes sujets*. (Fénelon)
>
> 4° *De* est souvent employé devant un complément non accompagné d'un déterminatif. *Par* s'emploie souvent devant un complément accompagné d'un déterminatif.
>
> - *Le peuple était accablé d'impôts.*
> - *Le peuple était accablé par ces impôts.*
>
> Hist. D'une manière générale, *de* était autrefois plus fréquent que *par* devant le complément d'agent du verbe passif. *Excité d'un désir curieux* (Racine)

Donc je dirais :

> Le roi a été adoré par son peuple :

Le verbe a son sens plein, l'accent est mis sur l'action, l'agent est plus mis en valeur.

> Le roi a été adoré de son peuple :

Le verbe *adorer* marque un sentiment et donc on emploie plus volontiers *de* pour introduire l'agent. Par ailleurs c'est le fait que le roi était adoré qui est mis en valeur.

Answer (score 3):

L'usage de ces deux préposition revient à la même signification ; on les trouve avec à peu près la [même fréquence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ador%C3%A9+par%2Cador%C3%A9+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cador%C3%A9%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cador%C3%A9%20de%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cador%C3%A9%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cador%C3%A9%20de%3B%2Cc0).

La différence est que dans la première phrase il s'agit du participe passé et que dans la second il s'agit de l'adjectif. Pourquoi le participe passé plutôt que l'adjectif n'est pas toujours facile à déterminer. Le verbe « être » de l'emploi passif indique cela avec la préposition « par » ([réf.1](https://wwwling.arts.kuleuven.be/alfagram/Temps/nperso/partpas/femploi.htm), [réf.2](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/454.html)). La préposition n'est cependant pas nécessaire pour qu'il s'agisse d'un passif.

- J'ai été averti au dernier moment de cette nouvelle sidérante. (*passif, ex. tiré d'une référence*)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ador%C3%A9))  II. Emploi adj. Adoré de. Un père adoré de ses enfants. Un maître adoré de ses élèves (Ac. 1878).

Sur le plan du sens les deux correspondent à cette dernière phrase mais sur le plan de la grammaire la première y correspond en tant que tournure à la voix passive.